# Connect to FTP server behind a NAT and Firewall without port forwarding

Tags: c#, ftp, port, forwarding, nat

I've a new issue to solve about NAT traversal.
I'm deploying a C# application that starts a FTP server when an event occur.
The issue is that the machine running the FTP server is behind a NAT/Firewall router so i cannot reach it from any external PC connected to the Internet.
So i want to be able to connect from my PC to the FTP server but port-formwarding is not an option.

I've read several articles about Hole punching, UPnP and so on but i cannot rely on UPnP since i don't know if a router supports it.

I've studied the issue of NAT traversal and at this point, the only way to solve this issue is to initiate the connection from the machine which is running the FTP server (in other way it should act as a client so that the NAT has a rule for the IP/PORT translation). However, i don't think any Windows FTP server has this feature.

Since i've a Remote VPS Server not Natted and where i can port-forward anything i want, i was thinking to create a tunnel between client and server trough the VPS.

FTP Server (Start the connection to the) --> VPS ---> Client  (Connection)

FTP Server <--- VPS <--- Client (reply)

However i don't know if there's a way to do what i explained or if there's some easyer way to do that.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly are you starting up an FTP server when an event occurs? Could you re architect your solution in a way that allows you to have the client connect out to another service when an event occurs? I ask this question in the hopes of understand more of the problem you are trying to solve and considering other alternatives to solving it.

Comment: I need to access to File & Folder on the machine and usually i use an FTP server to do so.
I can re-code the event handling and start something else if needed. What is your solution?

Comment: Instead of firing up an FTP server on a machine behind a NAT, couldn't you architect a solution where that machine establishes a connection to the outside and the code sends the data out? Or do you actually want to have full access to this machine in order to do something more than just get some files?

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to make sure your FTP server has a public IP address and listen to incoming FTP requests.

However I don't know if there's a way to do what I explained or if there's some easyer way to do that. Any help is appreciated.

What your are trying to do with this other solution is called using a proxy. It is also similar to a TURN like solution. If properly configured and if it has a public IP address, the proxy can surely forward traffic to your server once your server has established a connection with the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

one solution that could be erasing question is to add a rule to server containing this : your application name (or the port you use ,i don't recommend this) and allow action .
FYI this is not programming solution but it's a network solution.

Answer (score 0):

I use Open.NAT library. It opens port 21, and adds entry to UPnP table on the compatible modem/router. Checking port open online confirms connectivity.

Probably the best solution imho.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not developing application that will be used by other people, you can use something like Hamachi which creates virtual private network so it acts like computers are on LAN therefore making port forwarding not necesarry.